# Completed review item does not show whether you voted or followed the post anymore

Tags: bug, review, voting, follow-post

When you navigated back to a review queue item, at least in the First Posts queue, we used to be able to see whether we up- or downvoted, just like on the normal Q&A page. This is no longer the case, and when trying to vote again strange things happen to the score: the one between the vote controls changes, but the one in the header does not.

[image]

The problem extends to posts you've followed; you don't see that anymore either.