# Why is my vote not visible in the reviews which I completed?

Tags: bug, review, down-votes

I was reviewing answers from the First answers review queue in Ask Ubuntu.

I noticed a post which was not an answer. I downvoted the post, flagged it as 'not an answer' and completed the review.

I revisited the [review page](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-answers/1216828), and my vote wasn't visible.

[image]

So I clicked on downvote once again and then I got this error:

[image]

Please fix this issue.

Comment: Glorfindel reported this a short while ago: [Completed review item does not show whether you voted anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377682/completed-review-item-does-not-show-whether-you-voted-anymore)